# Flutter errors on Simulator after Firebase installation

Tags: flutter, dart

My Flutter app has been running fine, I then started the emulator today and these errors all flashed up from nowhere, running perfectly fine the last time it was open.

I began installing Firebase this morning but backed out halfway through to focus on something else. This was in another project yet all of my Flutter apps are unable to run now

I have tried all sorts of solutions, but it doesn't make sense for me to keep playing with the `ios` files and potentially messing things up further before I check if anyone knows what is going on.

All questions I have seen online are people who have been editing `subscriberCellularProvider`, I have never seen or heard of this before

My podfile etc is all set to 12.4 and has been working fine for a while before this.

When I have had errors before I have copied and pasted into a new folder and `flutter run` and all has fixed, but this won't work this time.

Any help appreciated

```
** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
/Users/alexander/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/permission_handler-8.3.0/ios/Classes/strategies/PhonePermissionStrategy.m:50:35: warning: 'subscriberCellularProvider' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 12.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      CTCarrier *carrier = [netInfo subscriberCellularProvider];
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                    serviceSubscriberCellularProviders
In module 'CoreTelephony' imported from /Users/alexander/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/permission_handler-8.3.0/ios/Classes/strategies/PhonePermissionStrategy.m:8:
  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/Headers/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.h:112:50: note: property 'subscriberCellularProvider' is declared deprecated here
  @property(readonly, retain, nullable) CTCarrier *subscriberCellularProvider API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("serviceSubscriberCellularProviders", ios(4.0, 12.0)) API_UNAVAILABLE(macos);
                                                   ^
  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/Headers/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.h:112:50: note: 'subscriberCellularProvider' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
2
  1 warning generated.
  Selected xcframework slice ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator
  rsync --delete -av --filter P .*.?????? --links --filter "- CVS/" --filter "- .svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/" "/Users/alexander/Documents/copy3/ios/Pods/../.symlinks/plugins/here_sdk/ios/Frameworks/heresdk.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator/*" "/Users/alexander/Documents/copy3/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/here_sdk"
  building file list ... rsync: link_stat "/Users/alexander/Documents/copy3/ios/Pods/../.symlinks/plugins/here_sdk/ios/Frameworks/heresdk.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator//*" failed: No such file or directory (2)
  done
  sent 29 bytes  received 20 bytes  98.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
  rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-54.120.1/rsync/main.c(996) [sender=2.6.9]
  Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
  note: Using new build system
  note: Building targets in parallel
  note: Planning build
  note: Constructing build description
  warning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select a development team in the Runner editor. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
  warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'Reachability' from project 'Pods')
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.
Exited (sigterm)
```